# Creating a graph inside Gremlin Server

Tags: graph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

We are planning to use tinkerpop for our project. 
I had a few doubts about this:

1. I see that there are GremlinServer.start() GremlinServer.stop() APIs which I can use to get gremlin server running in embedded style. This means it will not start any other process unlike when we execute gremlin server bash script. Is this correct?
2. My graph size could be large and so I may not want my graph to be in-memory always like it is the case with tinkerpop graph. So if I have my graph in gremlin server, how will it be stored? In memory only or is there a way to persist it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that depends on what you pass into the constructor as specified [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.1.4/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/GremlinServer.html#start--)
2. There are several persistence layers you can look into which implement the gremlin server API. For example you can go open source with [TitanDB](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/) or go for an enterprise solution with [DSE Graph](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-graph).